# Do Indonesians have laws that govern investment?

Tags: insurance, indonesia

A friend of mine was offered an investment by an insurance agent.

We basically understood that we can arrange that the insurance ia "small" and the rest is for real investment.

Even though he is not interested in the insurance part, he sort of agree because he can set the insurance small. He also had a lawyer that he trusted would warn him in case things go wrong.

The thing is the insurance agent is his lawyer's wife.

So what seems to happen is the lawyer, the insurance company, and the agent works together. What they seems to do from my point of few is the following

1. They set the "benefit" of the insurance small. So the insurance
   benefit can be bought for $40.
2. They set the premi high ($4000) to
   max out the commission. They seem to be able to do this due to a
   technique called unapplied premium.
3. They claim that all the money is
   invested.

Basically he ended up buying a $40 worth of insurance protection for $4k because he thought the money is all invested.

Needless to say he sued the insurance company under customer protection laws.

Latter the agent said that the insurance is indeed small like he asked (the benefit is small) and that unit link is "long term investment".

That being said we wonder if there is any additional laws that protect investors like me from this kind of scam.

The corporation name is avrist insurance. I've heard it's related to AIA or something. Not sure.

We got to keep names secret because of indonesian anti defamation's laws and the court in indonesia is very malleable. We do however, want the case to get as much publicity as possible.

The case is quite similar with http://news.asiaone.com/news/singapore/sim-lim-scams-student-reduced-tears-after-being-charged-1k-iphone-warranty except that you change iphone to investment. A little insurance that should worth so small suddenly worth a lot without customer knowing it.

Update: The customer sued the avrist in bpsk. Avrist didn't even bother showing up. However, it seems to be a very long road between that and getting the money back. It probably cost way more than $5k.

Comment: Was the lawyer representing your interests, or his own family's?  It seems like there's a conflict of interest there.

Comment: What are the terms of the investment?  Can you withdraw your money from it now? Have you tried?

Comment: We still don't know what you've tried.  Have you asked the agent (who seems to think or be willing to tell you it's all an investment) for a withdrawal of your shares or a return of your money? If she refused, what reasons were given in the refusal?

Comment: He put $10k. About $4k is already returned. Her reasoning is unit link is indeed "long term investment with a little insurance benefit" like he asked. Obviously he didn't expect a little insurance benefit would cost 100 times it's normal cost. He asked why did she set up USD 5k premi. She said, it's just how unit link works. Before he bought he didn't even know he is buying unit link. He was told he is buying investment

Comment: The agent said it's really investment and the customer tired of being lied too ask them to explain to a popular forum. They refused. They don't even say anything when sued on jakarta consumen resolution court. The court didn't usually have bite but agree to give the konsumen a default judgement.

Comment: The lawyer is representing the client's interest. However, with 90% probability, the lawyer is most likely just trying to milk the client.